# Deployment failed with Apex test class : CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY

Tags: apex

I'm trying to create test class for a custom object called "Partner Involvement" under opportunity, which identify the associated reseller or partner for the opportunity. it was working fine with previous sandbox but returning below errors when uploading to new sandbox environment.. could somebody advise me what is wrong with the coding?

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
> PartnerInvolvementTriggerAll: execution of AfterInsert caused by:
> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id
> 0063K0000025KUXQA2; first error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY,
> OpportunityTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate caused by:
> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
> error: CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY, OpportunityTrigger:
> execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.QueryException: unexpected
> token: 'FROM'
> Class.OpportunityRenewalCreation.createRenewalOpportunityWithProducts:
> line 71, column 1
> Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.processAfterUpdateWithList: line Stack
> Trace: Class.PartnerInvolvementTriggerAllTest.testCreateByJPCommunity:
> line 145, column 1

the Apex class is:

```
> @isTest public class PartnerInvolvementTriggerAllTest  {  @isTest
     public static void testOpportunityUpdate()
     {
         Account acc = new Account (Name = 'newAcc1',
                                    BillingCountry ='United Kingdom',
                                    Industry = 'Others',
                                    RecordTypeId = '01236000000OGv1'
                                   );        
         insert acc;
         
         Account acc1 = new Account (Name = 'newAcc2',
                                    BillingCountry ='Uganda',
                                    Industry = 'Others',
                                    RecordTypeId = '01236000001UOmp'
                                   );        
         insert acc1;
         
         Opportunity o = new Opportunity(Accountid = acc.id,
                                         StageName = 'Proposal',
                                         CloseDate = system.today(),
                                         Name = 'Test Op',
                                         Type = 'Upsell',
                                         Deal_Type__c = 'Resale',
                                         CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR',
                                         Led_by__c = 'Direct Led',
                                         LeadSource = 'Partner'                                                                            
                                        );        
         insert o;
         
         Partner_Involvement__c pic = new Partner_Involvement__c(Partner_Delivery_Role__c = 'Primary
 Implementation',
                                                                 Partner_Sales_Role__c = 'Sold to Partner (Buying Directly from
 UiPath)',
                                                                 Partner_Account_Name__c = acc1.Id,                                    
 
                                                                 CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
                                                                 PartnerOpp_Name__c = o.Id,
                                                                 Partner_Engagement__c = 'Fulfillment'
                                                                );
         
         test.startTest();
         
         insert pic; 
         
         //pic.Partner_Account_Name__c = acc1.Id;
         //pic.Partner_Role__c = 'VAR/Reseller';
         
         //update pic;
         
         test.stopTest();
         
         Opportunity oppTest = [select Id, Sold_to_Partner__c, Implementation_Partner__c from Opportunity where Id =
 :pic.PartnerOpp_Name__c];
         
         System.assertEquals(oppTest.Sold_to_Partner__c, acc1.Id);
         System.assertEquals(oppTest.Implementation_Partner__c, acc1.Id);
         
         delete pic;
     }
     
     @isTest
     public static void testCreateByJPCommunity() {
         //user
         String nowStr1 = String.valueOf(Datetime.now()).remove(':').remove(' ').remove('-') +
 '1';
         Account u_acc = new Account(
             Name = 'u_hogeAccount' + nowStr1,
             Country__c = 'Japan',
             Industry = 'Chemicals'
         );
         insert u_acc;
 
         Contact u_con = new Contact(
             LastName = 'u_hogeContact' + nowStr1,
             AccountId = u_acc.id
         );
         insert u_con;
 
         Profile u_prf = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'UiPath Japan Partner Community' LIMIT 1];
 
         User u = new User(
             Email = 'testCreByJP' + nowStr1 + '@example.com',
             profileid = u_prf.id,
             UserName = 'testCreByJP' + nowStr1 + '@example.com',
             Alias = 'testJP',
             TimeZoneSidKey='Asia/Tokyo',
             EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
             LocaleSidKey='ja_JP',
             LanguageLocaleKey='ja',
             ContactId = u_con.Id,
             PortalRole = 'Manager',
             FirstName = 'FirstName',
             LastName = 'LastName'
         );
         insert u;
 
         //account
         String nowStr2 = String.valueOf(Datetime.now()).remove(':').remove(' ').remove('-') +
 '2';
         RecordType rt = [SELECT Id, SobjectType, DeveloperName FROM RecordType WHERE SobjectType = 'Account' AND DeveloperName = 'Partner'
 LIMIT 1];
         Account acc1 = new Account(
             Name = 'testCreByJPAcc1' + nowStr2,
             Country__c = 'Uganda',
             Industry = 'Chemicals',
             OwnerId = u.Id,
             RecordTypeId = rt.Id
         );
         insert acc1;
 
         Account acc2 = new Account(
             Name = 'testCreByJPAcc2' + nowStr2,
             Country__c = 'Japan',
             Industry = 'Chemicals',
             OwnerId = u.Id,
             RecordTypeId = rt.Id
         );
         insert acc2;
 
         //opportunity
         Opportunity opp = new Opportunity(
             Accountid = acc1.id,
             StageName = 'Proposal',
             CloseDate = system.today(),
             Name = 'testCreByJPOpp',
             Type = 'Upsell',
             Deal_Type__c = 'Resale',
             CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR',
             Led_by__c = 'Direct Led',
             LeadSource = 'Partner',
             OwnerId = u.Id
         );
         insert opp;
 
         //partnerinvolvement
         Partner_Involvement__c pi = new Partner_Involvement__c(
             Partner_Delivery_Role__c = '',
             Partner_Sales_Role__c = 'Sold to Partner (Buying Directly from UiPath)',
             Partner_Account_Name__c = acc2.Id,
             CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD',
             PartnerOpp_Name__c = opp.Id,
             Partner_Engagement__c = '',
             OwnerId = u.Id
         );
 
         test.startTest();
 
         System.runAs(u) {
             insert pi;
         }
         
         test.stopTest();
     } }
```

Thank you and your help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

This is the class you should be looking into: **OpportunityRenewalCreation**
look for a malformed SOQL query on *line 71*

> unexpected token: 'FROM'
>   Class.OpportunityRenewalCreation.createRenewalOpportunityWithProducts:
>   line 71, column 1
>   Class.OpportunityTriggerHandler.processAfterUpdateWithList